# How to preview your website without the top WordPress admin bar, but remain signed in?

Tags: admin-bar, previews

Is there a way to preview your website without the top WordPress admin bar, but remain signed in?

Basically, want to continue making changes in the panel and review the site, but without the top admin bar...but don't want to sign in every time.  I don't want to remove the top bar...just don't want it there when I preview my changes, if that makes sense.  When working with the top header, I want to see it as users will see it.

Thank you!

Comment: Note, I saw when adjusting pages or products I could press preview, and I believe that didn't show the admin bar, but what about when adjusting the header?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OR you can go into your own user profile (hover over your name on the right end of the bar and click on Edit My Profile) and uncheck the box that says Show Toolbar when viewing site. Click Update Profile at the bottom of the page and the bar will go away.

Reverse the process when you want to bring it back.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy. Just put this in your plugin/theme or what have you:

```
function remove_teh_menu_barz() {

            add_filter('show_admin_bar', 'show_admin_bar');
}


function show_admin_bar() {

    return false;

}

add_action('init', 'remove_teh_menu_barz');
```

This hooks into the init action hook in wordpress and fires the function. The function drops in a filter(which references the show_admin_bar()) telling WP not to show the admin bar. Notice the return false; This will hide the admin bar, but still keep you logged in. You can also just do away with the initial action hook, and drop the call to the show_admin_bar into the filter on an early enough hook and it will do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can also: right click> open in incognito window

Comment: _remain signed in_ prevents that. :)